# save csv to server from mysql via php

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I can create a csv from mysql that is then saved on the user's computer via the code below.

```
        //Connecting to my database
        mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.");
        mysql_select_db($dbname);               


        // output headers so that the file is downloaded rather than displayed
        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=pikaObs_'.date("Ymd").'.csv');            


        // create a file pointer connected to the output stream
        $output = fopen('php://output', 'w');

        // output the column headings
        fputcsv($output, array('fid','firstName','lastName','email','phone','date','time','pikasSeen','haystacksSeen','pikasHeard','pikasDoing','habitatType','lattitude','longitude'));

        // fetch the data
        mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
        mysql_select_db($dbname);
        $rows = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM pikaObs');

        // loop over the rows, outputting them
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)) fputcsv($output, $row);
```

What I want to do now is write a php script that will save this csv to the server rather than prompting and storing on the user's machine.

Can I modify the above code to save a new file stamped with date time to a folder on the server?

Comment: Yes, you can.  Have you tried to do this yet?  Are you running into problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer: Let `$output` point to a file:

```
// create a file pointer connected to a file
$output = fopen('/path/to/yourfile', 'w+');
```

and remove the calls to `header()`